# Java scanner: input square root of a number

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, square-root

So I'm making a program where you are given an angle and you have to input the exact value of the sine, cosine, or tangent of the angle. Let's say the answer was 1/√(3), how would I be able to enter that as my answer, and compare it to the answer that the code calculated (1/Math.sqrt(3))?

Comment: and what have you done about it?

Comment: "input the exact *value*" is impossible, because the answer cannot be expressed *exactly* as a numeric value. You could however ask user to enter the value with N decimals of precision, and then verify that value is accurate to that precision.

Comment: By "exact value," I mean input the value in fraction form like it is in the question rather than a rounded decimal.

Comment: how do you suppose they could do that from the command line or terminal input?

Comment: They could enter something like 1/Math.sqrt(3) and it would work with my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be calculating the value of the user input String like so: [Evaluating a math expression given in string form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form)

Then you could go ahead and simply compare the result with your "the answer that the code calculated".